# Docker container for proxying ports to other containers of the stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, socat, docker-stack

I am currently using Docker Compose for deployment of services in stacks. A typical simplified configuration looks like this:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
   database:
     image: database-v1
     networks:
       - internal
   backend:
     image: backend-v1
     networks:
       - internal
       - external
   frontend:
     image: frontend-v1
     networks:
       - internal
       - external
   microservice:
     image: microservice-v1
     networks:
       - internal

networks:
  external:
    external: true
    name: macvlan
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

It works, but there are problems with this configuration. I can access backend and frontend containers from my external network, but with macvlan configuration, the network addresses are assigned sequentially, and the address would depend on which container starts first. In other words, I can tell for sure that these containers got the addresses `192.168.0.120` and `192.168.0.121` on my network, but I can not tell which one of these is backend and which one is frontend without checking, and if the stack is restarted, the addresses might be swapped. The other problem is not being able to access the database and microservice containers without connecting to the internal network. Sure, I can proxy connections to REST microservice through either backend or frontend, but this wouldn't work with the database unless it's exposing some sort of interface over HTTP. An alternative solution would be to just attach all the containers to the external network, but this is also not what I want, because of the first problem (sequential address assignment), and using too many addresses on my network, ideally it should be just one address per stack.

I am aware of Docker being able to forward ports and expose them from the host machine, and this is not what I want. I would like to add another container that would be the only one attached to both networks, and all TCP ports would be forwarded through it. Ideally, I imagine a configuration like this:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
   proxy:
     image: proxy-v1
     environment:
       PROXY_CONFIG: "frontend:80->80 backend:80->8080 microservice:50051->51 database:5432->5432"
     networks:
       - internal
       - external
   database:
     image: database-v1
     networks:
       - internal
   backend:
     image: backend-v1
     networks:
       - internal
   frontend:
     image: frontend-v1
     networks:
       - internal
   microservice:
     image: microservice-v1
     networks:
       - internal

networks:
  external:
    external: true
    name: macvlan
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

This would solve all the problems: the stack is only using one address on the external network (and it will be consistently `192.168.0.120` in my case), and all needed ports can be easily exposed through the proxy.

Was a similar configuration already implemented by someone? Is there an already existing container for just proxying TCP ports? I am looking at `socat` right now, and it looks like it can do what I want. Would there be any other problems with such configuration that I can't see at the moment?

Comment: Unless you need access directly to the database from outside, there's no need to proxy database traffic. Just have your backend talk to the database over the internal network. As for reverse proxying, Nginx and Traefik are propular choices and you should be able to find guides/tutorials with a bit of searching.

Comment: I know how to proxy HTTP traffic, no problem with that. What I am trying to do is passthrough a TCP port, so that I would be able to access the database (for example, use GUI tools for Postgres or Mongo management on my local machine) or connect to SSH server in a container.

Comment: The setup you're describing is almost exactly what Docker's normal port forwarding does.  If you delete all of the `networks:` blocks and add `ports:` to the individual containers as required, the stack would use only one address on the external network (the host's), and you can selectively remap ports or choose not to publish some of them at all.  Why not use that built-in functionality?

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I am aware of this function of Docker, and that I do not want to use it. Docker port forwarding would forward ports to the host IP, and I want exactly one IP per stack.

Comment: The fact your struggling to find a solution might suggest this is a bit of an anti-pattern, it certainly sounds and feels like it to me.

Comment: I do not know what in my question suggested that I am struggling to find a solution. In my opinion, I described the solution pretty well, and I am asking if something similar already was implemented.

Comment: In regards to the sequential IP assignment issue, using `depends_on` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on)) would control the workflow of IP assignments to services. I do not see evidence of that specific setting which is why I wanted to mention it.

Comment: Yes, `depends_on` can be used to control the order in which the containers are started. Unfortunately, it can't solve the other two problems.